# Matlab Switch-case

Tags: matlab, switch-statement

I'm trying to write a function that puts the class, length, and value of each of the things in a cell array into a struct, but I keep getting an error with the switch statements

```
function [ out, common ] = IDcell( cA )
%UNTITLED Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here
cl={};
val={};
len={};
for x=1:length(cA)
    switch cA(x)
        case isnum
            cl(x)='double';
        case ischar
            cl(x)='char';
        case islogical
            cl(x)='logical';
        case iscell
            cl(x)= 'cell';
    end

val=[val cA{x}];
len=[len size(value(x))];
end

out=struct('value', val, 'class', cl, 'length', len);


end





[out]=IDcell(cA)
SWITCH expression must be a scalar or string constant.
Error in IDcell (line 8)
switch cA(x)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`isnum` is not a Matlab function.  `isnumeric` may be what you were thinking of, but it isn't what you typed.  Which means your code is seeing `case isnum` and it has no idea what the heck `isnum` is, so it is telling you whatever it is, if you want to use it there you need to make it something that evaluates to a number (what it means by scalar) or to a piece of text (what it means by string constant).

Further, `ischar` is a matlab function, but you are not using it the right way.  You must use it as `ischar(cA(x))` for example, will then evaluate to `true` if `cA(x)` is a string or snippet of text, will evaluate to `false` if `cA(x)` is anything else.

While it would be lovely if `switch` worked this way, it doesn't.  You can't put a thing in the `switch` part, and then just list functions that need to be evaluated on that thing in the  `switch` part.

The kind of thing you can do is this:

```
switch class(x)
    case 'double'
        fprintf('Double\n');
    case 'logical'
        fprintf('Logical\n');
end
```

Here I have used the `class` function the way it needs to be used, with an argument in it.  And I then switch my cases based on the output of that function, class outputs a string.

Comment: of course, the Matlab-provided `class` function replaces almost his entire code